# Upgraded to 2.7.2: Fatal error: Class Matrix_cat_col_ft

Tags: matrix, php-errors, fatal

I just upgraded to EE 2.7.2 and am getting an error when I go navigate to Addons > Field Types.

Fatal error: Class Matrix_cat_col_ft contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in ***\expressionengine\third_party\matrix_cat_col\ft.matrix_cat_col.php on line 167

I've also upgraded to Matrix 2.5.8

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue lies with this add-on http://koivi.com/ee-matrix-cat-col which hasn't been updated for two years so is incompatible with EE2.7

Adding this (http://pastie.org/private/f3xjwmrrm97psclvuu3hq) to the third_party/matrix_cat_col.php class should help (right before the last "}").

Comment: Hi Andris, the code you posted makes the error go away but doesn't seem to enable the celltype, i.e. it doesn't show up in the list to choose from. I need this functionality, i.e. to be abel to enter a category ID by choosing from a dropdown. Do you know what else needs to be done to matrix_cat_col to make it fully compatible with 2.7.2?